# Unable to find WAR (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, war

I am trying to deploy a war file from my local filesystem using Jenkins on Tomcat. I have done everything I need going over tutorials, just not sure what to put in the file path of the WAR. I am using Eclipse to code and build the project into a WAR file. First I tried putting the path of the WAR file, but that gave an error saying:

```
Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'PATH_TO_WAR'
```

Then after searching through StackOverflow I learned that Jenkins doesn't like absolute paths. My war is being built on a on a different drive altogether. .jenkins folder is on the C drive and WAR is on the H drive.

The path to my WAR is:
H:\Workspace\tomcat_git\releases\my-type-controller\lib\MTC.war

How do make this a relative path?? Most of the tutorials I read are using something **/*.war and fancy stuff like git and maven, but I am not sure if that will work for me. My requirements are just do my builds and let Jenkins manage the deployment locally.

Comment: ok , if you are not sure about your local path to your war file, can you print the directory where your jobs is running . So if you using linux system do sh 'echo pwd' if you using window do bat "echo %cd%" to print the current directory, then you can easitly navigate to the path where the war file reside. You didnt mention any of this information. can you run it and share the output

Comment: I am trying to work on the Jenkins UI. I would assume the working directory would be the tomcat webapps folder wouldn't it? Or the .jenkins folder that the war file created?

Comment: no, its not, please print your current directory and you will see the exact path for your folder